"[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes" - I'm completely stumped
This is actually part of a training exercise, but I'm sure I'll need it for a Capstone project I'm working on. I've tried a couple of things, but a lot of what I looked up is confusing to me. Does anyone know of a simple way to fix this?...
My index.js code.
I've tried killing the server elsewhere and checking if I installed Express erroneously. I double-checked to make sure my files were saved and in proper syntax. Nothing changed. Some of the solutions I looked up were hard to follow, and I didn't want to risk messing up my files using the wrong thing.
The error in question is "listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use ::: 5000."

don't add code/error messages as pictures - the error is telling you that port 5000 is already in use by some other process

Oh, okay. Thanks for telling me. I'll remove it. As for the error itself, that's what's confusing me and that's why I was trying to kill the other processes using the server.

no, don't remove it, add the relevant part of the error and the relevant part of the code to the question, as text

Okay, I fixed it again. It's worth noting that I also looked at some of the files in the node modules, but didn't understand to look for.

The error message is telling you the address your server is trying to listen to is already in use EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000, probably you have another instance from a previous test running?
To test, try changing the port your server is listening to. Modify the line:
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {

to
var server = app.listen(5001, function () {


Thanks. I'll try that and see what it does. Edit: It worked. Thanks again.
